# Part of Apple SSD not accessible after failed bootcamp attempt

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

A couple of months back I tried installing windows through bootcamp on my system. For reasons I couldn't understand back then (and can't remember now), it failed. And as a result the total accessible size of my SSD somehow got reduced. Recently I upgraded to Catalina and it's still the same. I haven't tried formatting the SSD though. Disk Utility shows me the following:

[image]

[image]

Can someone please give me a pointer on what might be going wrong here?

[Edit]

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         91.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s3
   4:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s4
   5:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s5
   6:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s6
   7:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s7
   8:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s8

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +91.6 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     46.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.7 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *129.8 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SD            129.4 GB   disk2s2




diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
   Partition Offset:          209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 91.6 GB (91554295808 Bytes) (exactly 178816984 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes
```

Comment: Could you post the output from the commands `diskutil list` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the partitions after `disk0s2` can be returned to free space. The commands to do so are given below.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s8
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s7
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s6
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s5
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s4
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

Next, the following command adds the free space to the APFS container in the `disk0s2` partition.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got back all the missing storage space.